# Is it UB to keep a const-reference to a local variable?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, standards, undefined-behavior

I'm running into multiple problems when compiling my code optimizations enabled (MSVC to be precise). The actual case is part of a large codebase and requires a complex setup to replicate, but essentially it boils down to the following construct:

```
struct VariableView
{
    const void* pValue;
};

template<typename Type>
[[nodiscard]] VariableView createView(const Type& value)
{
    return {&value};
}

void serializeStruct(Struct value)
{
    const auto view = createView(value);

    serializeGeneric(view);
}
```

The bug I'm experiencing revolves around the content of "value" becoming overwritten after "createView" is called but before/right at the point that "serializeGeneric" is called. This is as far as I've been able to tell via debugging and looking at the generated assembly, so what I'm assuming is that the compiler somehow (wrongly) assumes that the variable "value" is no longer used after createView is called, and thus decides to reassign the next required values to its original local.

However, before I file a bug-report to the MSVC-compiler, I'd like to make sure: Is what I'm doing here actually supposed to be valid C++ due to the standard, or am I running into UB by storing the address of the local variable in the "VariableView"-struct the way I'm doing it?

EDIT: Ok, so I've been able to boil down the problem. The compilers confusion seems to be coming from the fact that the type in the actual code is deduced by a template. This is the full code to reproduce the problem:

https://www.paste.org/120337
(Sorry, the editor keeps saying my code is not properly formatted so I had to use an external site).

In MSVC with /O2, the first two variables of the "Temporary" struct in accessData will be corrupted (O1 or below solves the issue. Passing the string_view by value seems to be what causes the values to be overwritten.
The bug actually also disappears if I replace the type-traits in the argument-list their plain definition, even though the trait resolves to the very same underlying type. So, please let me know if you think there is something else fishy here that I'm missing, but I'll be filing a bug-report as well since I'm now very sure that its not right (and also I now have a minimal example).

EDIT2: My report has been filed (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Type-trait-as-argument-type-leads-to-opt/1572875) and is already under investigation.

Comment: It is significantly more likely that there is a problem elsewhere in your code that is causing the problem rather than it being a compiler bug. At the very least, you need to provide a [MCVE] for this type of question. The result of UB can often be observed far from where it is caused, the cause of the problem doesn't have to be near where you see a problem.

Comment: To answer what was asked : the lifetime of `value` is independent of `view.pValue` and it will always outlive it in this case. There isn't anything obviously wrong with the code.

Comment: You’re not, it all seems valid C++ up to the serialization; note if serializeGeneric contains UB, the compiler is free to do anything anyway, so I’d replace that with a no-op function call and see if it repeats (provided this example is capable of reproducing the bug).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Does the same apply to the lifetime, if the compiler cannot see the constexpr of VariableView? Thats what happening in practice, and thats also whats happening with serializeGeneric.
I'll try to get a sample to reproduce, but I'm confident that its exactly as I described. While I wasn't able to reproduce in isolation just yet, I was able to extract the piece of code that caused the bug into an empty project, with no additional code called before or after, so there should not be any UB other than this code.

Comment: The pastebin code is different. You take the address of `value` which is a function local object the function returns a dangling pointer. This leads to UB in `AccessData` when you dereference it. In the code provided in the question `value` was a reference.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No, they should both be exactly the same. The value passed into the top-level function is a local, and create(Const)VariableView takes a reference in both cases (ConstAttributeSemantic evaluates down to const& as well via std::add_reference_t). Or are you talking about something else? Sorry if the names are confusing, there are two similar "semantic" traits here which do different things in the real code.

Comment: `createConstVariableView(ConstAttributeSemantic<Type> value)` is taking the address of `value` which is not a reference.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  Yes it is? ConstAttributeSemantic<Type> is essentially a typedef for const Type&. You can test this by removing std::add_const_t and then write a function that modifies "value" - it will change the variable that is passed in.

Comment: @Juliean You're right about it being a reference. I'm not used to seeing an alias for a reference type... I tried your example with MSVC and was not able to reproduce the problem. Note : I had to change the `#include` in `main.cpp` as `"ConstVariableView.h"` was not provided, so I assumed you meant `"Helper.h"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238909/discussion-between-juliean-and-francois-andrieux).